# Compatibility Issue with Internet Explorer 11 and ASP Boilerplate SPA: 'abp' Is Undefined Error

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, asp.net-core-2.0, typescript2.0, aspnetboilerplate

I can run this ASP Boilerplate project (.NET Core 2.0 with Angular 5) on Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and even Microsoft Edge. But I **cannot run this on Internet Explorer 11**. It gives this error:
    `ERROR ReferenceError'abp' is undefined`

[image]

My guess is that IE11 is not able to support the `abp` module for Angular 5. Is there any way to make it compatible with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is an issue with angular-cli and aot, see

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5762.

You can disable aot and try to see if it solves the problem like explained in here

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5762#issuecomment-291798471